# Bazel out-of-source build

Tags: bazel, build-system

I was recently introduced to 'Bazel' build system while learning gtest. Apparently I am a
beginner in this thing. So far it is going well, I really appreciate bazel's simplicity. My question is:

**How to build a bazel project outside the source directory? (Where my WORKSPACE file resides).**

In the build process bazel generates directories like "bazel-bin" and other directories in "bazel-*" form. I want these directories to be in a specific folder and not just cluttered around in the main root source directory, My WORKSPACE file resided in the main source directory. I would like all these files to be in a directory like "build" which itself resides in the root source directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.bazelrc` file with the following content:

```
build --symlink_prefix=/ # Out of source build
```

This avoids that Bazel specific symlinks are created in our source dir. If you have already such symlink dirs do a `bazel clean` to get rid of them and then create the `.bazelrc` file.

Consider also the [Bazel Documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--symlink_prefix) about the `--symlink-prefix` flag.